# How to join temporary table in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Originally problem is to retrieve documents from DB in the same order with given list of IDs. Using raw SQL I can do it like this

```
select c.id, c.ctime
from clusters c 
join (
   values 
      (910453, 5),
      (910483, 2),
      (910496, 1),
      (910503, 4),
      (910508, 3)
) as x (id, ordering) on c.id = x.id
order by x.ordering
```

Is there any way to do that using sqlalchemy? Besides, the resulting type of data should be sqlalchemy QuerySet, so I can not use python's *sorted*.

Answer (score 0):

Use follwing query:-

```
select c.id, c.ctime
from clusters c 
join (
      SELECT (910453 AS id, 5 AS ordering) UNION ALL
      SELECT (910483, 2) UNION ALL
      SELECT (910496, 1) UNION ALL
      SEELCT (910503, 4) UNION ALL
      SELECT (910508, 3)
     ) as x on c.id = x.id
order by x.ordering
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but problem is to do the same thing using sqlalchemy, not raw SQL.